# dnd-3.5e Warmage Edge damage to Wounding Spell damage per turn

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature, spellcasting, metamagic

Does Warmage Edge's additional damage apply to the damage per round caused by the Wounding Spell metamagic when applied to an instantaneous duration damaging spell?

"If a spell deals damage for more than 1 round, it deals this extra damage in each round." per the Complete Arcane version of the Warmage base class.

"When affected by this feat, a spell that deals damage to a creature also inflicts a bleeding wound that does not heal normally. On each subsequent round, the victim loses 1 hit point at the beginning of your turn." per Wounding Spell from Lost Empires of Faerun.

Wounding Spell's text indicates that if the spell does damage, it continues doing damage per round. Which could mean "the spell deals for more than 1 round."

For this reason i suspect Warmage Edge applies to the bleeding each round, but have found no validation anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! I don't want to read too much into this question, but does this question assume that each impact of a spell—like each individual *magic missile* or each ray of a *scorching ray* spell—also inflicts a bleeding wound if the spell is modified by the metamagic feat Wounding Spell? Either way, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan 
Thanks! I failed to determine whether each impact from the above mentioned spells would apply damage per round from Wounding Spell. In the context of this question my answer will be no, though I'll happily accept an experienced opinion. The specific case i would like a ruling on is a 'single impact' area spell, such as _Hail of Stone_ (Complete Arcane).

Answer (score 2):

### No.

The Wounding Spell feat says that the victim loses 1 hp per turn beecause of the wound, not that the spell keeps damaging the target dealing 1 damage on each subsequent turn.

The bleeding, not being damage from the spell but from the wound, does not benefit from Warmage Edge.

Comment: The wound... that the spell caused. I’m not so confident that the two can be separated. I’m not confident saying they definitely can’t be separated, either, so I’m not saying you’re wrong, just that I’m not sure you’re right.

Comment: @KRyan If the wound from the Wounding Spell feat means that the spell now deals damage, then the Wounding Spell feat causes any spell to meet its own requirement for application. I mean, it wouldn't be the first time somebody'd written something dumb for this game, but it seems to be a more carefully crafted feat than that.

Comment: @HeyICanChan But you can’t apply it to something that doesn’t already qualify in the first place, so you would never get the opportunity to bootstrap like that? I’m maybe not seeing the issue? If it just said the spell did damage on subsequent turns, there would be no problem that I can see, but this answer would be different.

Comment: @KRyan Probably? I mean, who knows, because the feat doesn't do that. I'd like this answer to add something like *A house rule saying that warmage's edge **does** apply is perfectly reasonable because warmage is terrible and this feat is terrible.* I mean, it's not like allowing this will break the game anyway. The Wounding Spell feat is a +2 spell level adjustment; this might be the only way it's ever-so-slightly impactful.

Comment: @KRyan as I see it, it's kind of trying to use maximize to increase the damage dealt by the natural attacks of a summoned monster. The summoned monster is not the spell, the spell summons the monster which then does the damage. This spell makes a wound that then bleeds, no further need for the spell to be there (the wound would bleed even in an AMF)

Comment: @Zachiel I fully understand that this is how you see it. I just don’t know that it’s _the correct_ way to see it.

Comment: @KRyan Out of curiosity, why read the Wounding Spell feat as saying *On each subsequent round, the victim is dealt 1 point of damage at the beginning of your
turn* when it says *On each subsequent round, the victim loses 1 hit point at the beginning of your turn*? Or are they synonymous, a distinction without a difference?

Comment: @HeyICanChan SRD: "**Loss Of Hit Points**: The most common way that your character gets hurt is to take lethal damage and lose hit points. ", so damage taken = hit points lost, it seems.